# Change image of UIButton on select or unselect

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uipickerview, ibaction

I want in my iOS app user can select some field on clicking the `UIButton`.

I want when user selects the field on click of `UIButton`,image of button should change and open my `MMPickerView` and when user clicks again the `UIButton` should get unselected and display previous image in `UIButton` and do not open `MMPickerview` at this time.

This is my code:

```
 - (IBAction)showPickerViewButtonPressed:(id)sender {
      if( (_button.selected = !_button.selected))
      {
           UIImage *bimage=[UIImage imageNamed: @"play.jpg"];
           [_button setImage:bimage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
      } 
      else
      {
           [MMPickerView showPickerViewInView:self.view
                       withStrings:_stringsArray
                       withOptions:@{MMbackgroundColor: [UIColor blackColor],
                                     MMtextColor: [UIColor whiteColor],
                                     MMtoolbarColor: [UIColor blackColor],
                                     MMbuttonColor: [UIColor whiteColor],
                                     MMfont: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18],
                                     MMvalueY: @3,
                                     MMselectedObject:_selectedString}
                        completion:^(NSString *selectedString) {

                            _label.text = selectedString;
                            _selectedString = selectedString;
             }];
         }
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are not changing button's state. Try this...

```
- (IBAction)showPickerViewButtonPressed:(id)sender 
{
   if ([_button isSelected])
   {
      _button.selected=NO;
   } 
   else
   {
      _button.selected=YES; // change button's state
           [MMPickerView showPickerViewInView:self.view
                   withStrings:_stringsArray
                   withOptions:@{MMbackgroundColor: [UIColor blackColor],
                                 MMtextColor: [UIColor whiteColor],
                                 MMtoolbarColor: [UIColor blackColor],
                                 MMbuttonColor: [UIColor whiteColor],
                                 MMfont: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18],
                                 MMvalueY: @3,
                                 MMselectedObject:_selectedString}
                    completion:^(NSString *selectedString) {

                        _label.text = selectedString;
                        _selectedString = selectedString;
                     //    _button.selected=YES;  change button's state here If you want to change state after completion.
                    }];
   }
}
```

And write this code where you declared your button.

```
  UIImage *bSelectedimage=[UIImage imageNamed: @"your image name for selected state"]; 
  UIImage *bimage=[UIImage imageNamed: @"your image name for default state"]; 
 [_button setImage:bSelectedimage forState:UIControlStateSelected];
 [_button setImage:bimage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 3):

`UIImage *bimage=[UIImage imageNamed: @"play_select.jpg"];
[_button setImage:bimage forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[_button setImage:bimage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];`

where button is declared

Answer (score 1):

For setting image to the button use the setbackground image instead of setimage

```
[<buttoninstane> setBackgroundImage:<#(UIImage *)#> forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[<buttoninstane> setBackgroundImage:<#(UIImage *)#> forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Write the above code where the button is declared

And in the button action use the below edited code

```
    - (IBAction)showPickerViewButtonPressed:(id)sender {
        if(_button.selected ){
[_button setSelected:NO];
          }
      else{
[_button setSelected:YES];
           [MMPickerView showPickerViewInView:self.view
                   withStrings:_stringsArray
                   withOptions:@{MMbackgroundColor: [UIColor blackColor],
                                 MMtextColor: [UIColor whiteColor],
                                 MMtoolbarColor: [UIColor blackColor],
                                 MMbuttonColor: [UIColor whiteColor],
                                 MMfont: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18],
                                 MMvalueY: @3,
                                 MMselectedObject:_selectedString}
                    completion:^(NSString *selectedString) {

                        _label.text = selectedString;
                        _selectedString = selectedString;
                    }];
                }
             }
```

Comment: @ Ramesh thanks i have applied you code but its not meet my requirements.Same things are happening.

Answer (score 1):

To set different image in different button status use
`- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image forState:(UIControlState)state;`

In your code the if statement `(_button.selected = !_button.selected)` will always be true， so the else part will never run.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4

add this where button is declared

`let bimage = UIImage(named: "play_select.jpg")
button.setImage(bimage, for: .selected)
button.setImage(bimage, for: .highlighted)`